# Switching from PHP to Objective-C

Tags: php, objective-c

I've been a PHP developer for a year now, however, I want to learn Objective-C to create desktop applications for mac in. I tried however to read some of the getting started tutorials on the Apple developer site, I didn't get much out of it as, I could make the apps in the tutorials but the code made no sense.

So where do I need to start? Do I need to start off with command line programs? If so, how would that work?

How is it best for me to use my knowledge of PHP to learn Objective-C?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your knowledge of PHP won't help much, it's best to follow Objective-C lessons and tutorials. Watch some web casts for beginners to get you headed in the right direction.

The only "PHP" knowledge that truly carried over for me was MVC...and that's not PHP. Everything else was basically starting from scratch.

Comment: all right, thanks, I'll ditch the PHP and pretend I've never seen a line of code and learn it from there :)

Comment: @fermionoid definitely look at the free iTunes U courses. Youtube has tons of great content as well. Feel free to email me with questions as well, I'd love to help!

Comment: thanks a million :) is there some friending system on stack overflow?

Comment: @fermionoid nope, but check my profile. There's a link to my website and you'll have direct access to my email.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I found it!

Answer (score 1):

When I first started with Objective-C and iOS, I read ['Programming in Objective-C, Fourth Edition, Developer's Library' by Stephen G. Kochan](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321811909). It is a very good step-by-step guide, assuming little to no prior knowledge.

Kochan makes use of the command line to teach the basics, with GUI programming appearing later in the book.

Unless you need to know how to release/retain references because you are working with preexisting code, I recommend picking up the fourth edition because it is geared toward usage of ARC (automatic reference counting), and iOS 5.

Edit: It looks like Kochan's book does not cover building GUI applications on Mac. But it is an excellent intro to Objective-C.

Comment: i would love to mark this as the answer but Raphael came up with a similar one before you :) I've still upvoted it

Answer (score 0):

There aren't command line programs with Objective-C not in the traditional sense. You can print output to the terminal inside Xcode if you want. That's not a terrible place to start but I would recommend just looking at everything, including UI. You first have to download Xcode and then I'd recommend watching Paul Haggerty's course on iTunes U. He gives an intro to the language. Php and Objective-C aren't really similar languages, it's similar to languages like C and C++. And they're used to do two totally different things.

EDIT:

Also for the sake of learning things, take a look at [Apress](http://www.apress.com). There's some awesome books there and that's how I first got into it. However, nothing beats just playing with the language and frameworks. It'll take you a while to become proficient but it's so worth it.

Comment: My interpretation is that the OP is asking if writing a command line application in Objective-C is the first learning step.

Comment: thanks shadow for the clarification, i thought of php because i read that php is part of the C family and so is objective-c...

Comment: Yes and no, Objective-C method syntax is something I had never seen before. You'll recognize some familiar mechanisms like for in loops and whatnot. But since method calls are the biggest part of objective-c along with delegate methods and MVC, the only thing that really carries over is general programming familiarity.

Comment: @ta.speot.is, if you mean programs that just print output to the command line with no Mac UI, then I'd still say no. My apologies though, I was thinking command line as in outside of XCode. Either way, I would dive in headfirst, read some books, and fiddle around with everything, including UI.